# JS ES6 IIFE + Symbol & Prototype - Adding to Instance?

Tags: javascript, prototype, instance, symbols, iife

I realize my question's title  may be worded weirdly, so I apologize up front. 
To be clear, I am referring to this:

```
var IIFE = (function () {
    var a = Symbol("a");
    function IIFE() {
        this["a"] = null;
    }
    IIFE.prototype = {
        get a() { return this[a]; },
        set a(n) { this[a] = n; }
    }
    return IIFE;
}());
var iife = new IIFE;
```

I want to dynamically add 'b' & 'c' using an array:

`var arrProps = ['b','c'];`

to an instance of IIFE. I don't care how it gets done, so as long as the values specified within `arrProps` can be accessed & assigned the same as you would with 'a' inside the instance, outside the instance, and within prototype get/set. An example of using 'b' would be:

- inside the instance: `this["b"] = value;`
- outside of the instance: `iife.b = value;`
- prototype set/get: `this[b] = value;`

As far as the get/set internals go, there is nothing more than just getting the value and setting value.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you also want the set value to not be directly visible to the outside, is that right? (you'd want to force property access to go through a getter?)

Comment: Maybe object would be better choice to do the things, since 
`iife.b = value; (first time)/*for next time*/ iffe.value = newValue ?`

Comment: In a lot of the attempts that I have made have resulted in the get/set for b showing up as a child of IIFE (where a's set/get shows up as a child of IIFE.__proto__) which results in b's set/get calling itself rather than setting or getting a value.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a Symbol, have the function return a Proxy instead, and you can use its `get` and `set` traps to check for accesses/assignments to arbitrary properties:

```js
const proxy = new Proxy({}, {
  get(obj, prop) {
    console.log('getting');
    return obj[prop];
  },
  set(obj, prop, newVal) {
    console.log('setting');
    return obj[prop] = newVal;
  },
});

proxy.a = 'aVal';
console.log(proxy.a);
proxy.b= 'bVal';
proxy.c = 'cVal';
proxy.a = 'anotherAVal';
```

Comment: Can you expand upon your answer, showing it as applied to IIFE and how it would work when iterating over the array as stated?

Comment: You don't need an IIFE at all, since you can simply declare a Proxy. Everything inside the `new Proxy(` is essentially private - its contents can't be accessed from outside without going through the setters or getters on the Proxy.

Comment: To assign new properties to the proxy, use the same technique as the code in the snippet - eg `proxy.a =` will call the setter trap, and referencing `proxy.a` as an expression will call the getter trap. So you just need to take the array items and do the same thing.